# Docker tag with date no longer functions in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab-ci, sbt-native-packager

Previously, I've managed to tag my latest images and push them to Gitlab container registry without any problem for months. However, I've noticed ever since yesterday that Gitlab no longer managed to push my images to its container repository. Here is the stacktrace:

```
[info] Built image project with tags [0.1-SNAPSHOT, latest]
[success] Total time: 285 s (04:45), completed Dec 13, 2020, 8:56:34 PM
$ docker tag project:latest registry.gitlab.com/group/project:0.1-SNAPSHOT-$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S)
$ docker push registry.gitlab.com/group/project
Using default tag: latest
The push refers to repository [registry.gitlab.com/group/project]
tag does not exist: registry.gitlab.com/group/project:latest
```

I can manage to push images by tagging them as such but it is not what I wish to have, since I'd like to differentiate between my images.

```
    - sbt docker:publishLocal
    - docker tag project:latest registry.gitlab.com/group/project
    - docker push registry.gitlab.com/group/project
```

I have no changes in my gitlab.yml file and I don't understand why it started to fail all of a sudden. Any help or pointers are appreciated.

Comment: What image did you use on the CI? I suspect an [update in Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker?tab=tags) broke the push.

Comment: For the record, exactly hit this one: https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/40302

Comment: So basically the default docker CLI behavior changed from "push all tags" to "push the latest `tag`" (when a tag is not specified)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, `docker push` stopped working during Friday and today.

I fixed this by using a previous image of Docker:

```yaml
 push:
     tags:
       - dind
     stage: push
-     image: docker:latest
+     image: docker:19.03.13
     services:
         - docker:dind
     variables:
         DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay
```

---

It corresponds to the recent release of the stable 20.10 version on Docker Hub: https://hub.docker.com/_/docker?tab=tags&page=1&ordering=last_updated&name=20.10

Answer (score 1):

I actually solved it by changing my script to push a specific tag instead of latest.

```
  script:
    - sbt docker:publishLocal
    - docker tag project:latest registry.gitlab.com/group/project:0.1-SNAPSHOT-$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M)
    - docker push registry.gitlab.com/group/project:0.1-SNAPSHOT-$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M)
```